# How to use JSON data in a view?

Tags: jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using now the following code in my Edit button in the flexigrid:

```
var url = '/Client/Details/' + id ;
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    //  setFormControls(data.Id, data.Role, data.Location, data.JobType, data.Description);
    alert(data);
});
//location.replace(url);
RunModalDialog("Edit Client: " + ClientName);
```

And my form is a bit complex view like this

```
@model CardNumbers.Models.ClientViewModel
 @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "sform", title = "Client Info" }))

 {    
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Client Info</legend>

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ClientId)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Number, EditorTemplate.TextBox)

    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, EditorTemplate.TextBox)

    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Client.Address, EditorTemplate.EditBox)

...
```

where EditorFor is a custom EditorFor. So, it will be a bit hard to manually translate returned json data into forms properties. I am wondering may be there is some simple method to do this kind of translation? I looked into knockout.js but I am not using it in my project (yet), so I am wondering if there is anything else?

Thanks in advance for help.

UPDATE. Just to make my question clearer I am adding a bit more info.

My main view is:

```
@model CardNumbers.Models.ClientViewModel

   @section scripts {
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Clients.js")" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    }

   <form id="frmClientsSearch">
    <label for="clientNo">Client No: </label>
    <input type="number" name="searchClientNo" class="numericOnly" /><br />
    <label for="clientName">Client Name: </label>
    <input type="search" size="25" value="Please enter the search value"      class="SelectOnEntry"
        name="searchClientName" />

       <input type="button" id="btnClientsSearch" value="Find / Refresh" />
    </form>
    <div style="padding-left: 150px; padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;"    id="ClientsResults">
    <table id="flexClients" style="display: none">
       </table>
    </div>

    <div id="editor" style="visibility:hidden">
       @Html.Partial("_ClientForm", Model);
    </div>
```

And my js file has the following:

```
    var $dlg = $("#sform").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: "blind",
    closeOnEscape: true,
    resizable: true,
    width: 1200,
    height: 750,
    minHeight: 600,
    minWidth: 950
    });

    function RunModalDialog(title, url)
{    
    if (title)
        $dlg.dialog("option", {"title": title });

    if (url)
    {        
        $dlg.load(url).dialog("option", { "title": title }).dialog("open");
    }
        //$dlg.load(url, function () {
        //    var validator = $("#sform").validate();
        //    if (validator)
        //         validator.resetForm();
        //    $dlg.dialog("option", { "title": title }).dialog("open");
        //});
    else {
        var validator = $("#sform").validate();
        if (validator)
            validator.resetForm();
        $dlg.dialog("open");
       }
    }

    function add(com, grid) {
    $('#fntype').val('Add');
    var url = '/Client/Add/'
    //location.replace(url);
    RunModalDialog("Create New Client");

   // clearForm();

   }

     function edit(com, grid)
      {
        $('.trSelected', grid).each(function () {

                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                id = id.substring(id.lastIndexOf('row') + 3);
                currentId = id;
                $('#fntype').val('Edit');
                var ClientName;
                ClientName =$('.trSelected td:eq(2)').text();
                var url = '/Client/Edit/' + id ;

                $.getJSON(url, function (html) {
                    //  setFormControls(data.Id, data.Role, data.Location, data.JobType, data.Description);
                    // alert(data);
                    $('#editor').html(html);
                });
               //location.replace(url);
               RunModalDialog("Edit Client: " + ClientName);
        });

    }
```

And now I see the same behavior for Add and Edit, e.g. Edit does not show data.
[What I see now http://www.universalthread.com/Thread%20photos/2013/01562893.jpg](http://www.universalthread.com/Thread%20photos/2013/01562893.jpg)

Comment: Darin, I don't understand why the dialog comes blank. The get request returns correct HTML yet the dialog shows empty form. I'm updating my original post to include picture

Comment: Darin, did you get my files? Were they Ok? I tried to work on the Save button for Add in the meantime and unfortunately it also returns ModelState.IsValid false for perfectly valid model. So, no progress there either :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make it easier, simply put the code you have shown in a partial view and then have the Details controller action return this partial view. Now when you invoke this action with AJAX it will return the updated contents of the partial that you could directly replace in your DOM. This way you don't need to be bothering with binding the JSON values to your form elements.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    ClientViewModel model = ...
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

and then:

```
var url = '/Client/Details/' + id ;
$.getJSON(url, function (html) {
    $('#someContainerDiv').html(html);
});
```

`#someContainerDiv` used in my example will obviously be defined in your main view:

```
<div id="someContainerDiv">
    @Html.Partial("Details", Model)
</div>
```

The partial will then contain the form you have shown in your question.

Comment: I see, let me try this idea now. I really have been struggling with that whole concept for a while and tried many different ways to get Edit button of the flexigrid correctly when I first need to get the row data from the server.

Comment: BTW, will this work with jquery dialog? In other words, I want to show the above as a modal form. My main view has this:  <div id="editor" style="visibility:hidden">
    @Html.Partial("_ClientForm", Model);
</div> and then RunModalForm is a function that opens #sForm as a dialog

Comment: Of course that it will work with jQuery dialog. All you have to do is configure your dialog with the container div.

Comment: Darin, 
Somehow it's not working. E.g. the form still opens empty even though the method is called. I do not know how to trace if the view is getting correct values or not.

Comment: It's simple: Use FireBug and you will immediately see the exact request/response payloads of your AJAX requests.

Comment: I am going to add right now a bit of code into my original question as I still can not make it work correctly

Comment: I've been testing with IE but let me test with FireFox now then

Comment: You've been testing with IE??? Seriously? You are doing web development with IE??? That's like a deaf man composing music - you have to be a true genius to do that.

Comment: I am testing from VS 2012 and I switch between different browsers. IE allow to trace JavaScript code.

Comment: BTW, I posted more code just in case - may be you'll see my problem right away

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22789/discussion-between-naomi-and-darin-dimitrov)

Comment: Darin,

Do you see why the form opens blank even though the call returns perfect HTML?

Comment: By *blank* you mean the input fields do not have values? Maybe there's a problem in the controller action that is supposed to return this partial view? Are you passing a model?

Comment: Hi Darin, yes, I am passing the model. I can see that the HTML returned is correct, all fields do have correct values. But yet the dialog that opens opens with values not populated. I updated the original message with more info, can you take a look, please? Or may be there is another way for us to discuss this? I really hope to finish this with your help now.

Comment: Sorry there's lot of information missing from your code. Could you please show a concise and yet complete example allowing to reproduce the problem? Hardcoded values for your model properties are just fine. Also if you could strip all the necessary noise such as classes and styles that would be great.

Comment: I am not exactly sure how can I do that? I can email you, if needed, my Clients model class, two of my views, my Js files. Or I can even email the whole project. Basically, I am using flexigrid and I started from this sample http://mvc4beginner.com/Sample-Code/Insert-Update-Delete/Asp-.Net-MVC-Ajax-Insert-Update-Delete-Using-Flexigrid.html but I introduced much more complexity down the road

Comment: Yes, mail me, I will take a look.

Comment: In other words, I have rather complex Clients class. On top of it I created ClientViewModel class (in the Models folder of Web project). I created EditorFor templates based on Sergey B blog post (we discussed it in another thread and I added my solution today). So, I am not exactly sure how can I simplify my project to only demonstrate the problem. I believe what I posted in the message should show it

Comment: Mail the whole project or just relevant pieces (e.g. classes, js file and 2 views)?

Comment: Just relevant pieces. It should compile and illustrate the problem.

Comment: I just sent everything I have. The Web project is huge (2MB zipped) and may be not everything is used, but I just put to zip all folders except for bin and obj

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment earlier as I was zipping up stuff.

Comment: I sent everything - hopefully you received and don't have troubles compiling. The solution consists of 3 projects (4th project is just for tests). I sent all 3 in 3 separate emails + 1 email with DB script.

Answer (score 0):

With Jazzen Chen help we solved this problem. All I needed to change is to use get instead of getJSON in the above. Now my form shows up with data correctly.